# Есть два графика lineplot в одной оси координат. Один из графиков почему-то сдвинут по оси x

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Есть два файла в формате json. По ним нужно построить два графика на одной оси координат.
По оси "y"(value) значения в обоих файлах одинаковые. По оси "x" (time), различаются.
Графики построил, но на выходе получаю ситуацию, что второй график (зелёный) сдвинут по оси x. Как будто у графиков разные нулевые координаты.
(+ скрин) В чём может быть проблема ?
Скрин : https://ibb.co/DYs2zDR

Исходные данные для зелёного графика, где все точки по оси "x" сдвинуты :

```
{
"two": [
    {
        "time" : "2022-06-20 00:00:03.044",     <-- реальная первая точка по оси x   
        "value" : 1.598E-4                        для зелёного графика
    },                                            На графике эта точка смещена
    {                                             до значения 2022-06-20 00:00:34.438
        "time" : "2022-06-20 00:00:04.849",       см. скрин
        "value" : 1.5987E-4
    },
    {
        "time" : "2022-06-20 00:00:04.970",
        "value" : 1.5988E-4
    },
    {
        "time" : "2022-06-20 00:00:09.383",
        "value" : 1.5989E-4
    },....
```

Исходные данные для красного графика, с ним всё ок:

```
{
"one": [
    {
        "time" : "2022-06-20 00:00:03.055",   тут всё ок, координаты красного графика
        "value" : 1.598E-4                    соответствуют данным исходным данным
    },                                         из файла
    {
        "time" : "2022-06-20 00:00:04.859",
        "value" : 1.5987E-4
    },
    {
        "time" : "2022-06-20 00:00:04.980",
        "value" : 1.5988E-4
    },
    {
        "time" : "2022-06-20 00:00:09.391",
        "value" : 1.5989E-4
    },...
```

Код:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import seaborn as sn
import json

f = open('one.json')
d = json.load(f)
print(d)
f.close()

f1 = open('two.json')
d1 = json.load(f1)
print(d1)
f1.close()


df = pd.DataFrame(d['one'])  #red
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1['two']) #green


sn.set()
sn.set_style("darkgrid", {'grid.linestyle': '--'})
p = sn.lineplot(x='time',y='value',color='r', data=df)
p1 = sn.lineplot(x='time',y='value',color='g', data=df1)

p.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(3))
p1.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(3))

p.set_xlabel('time', fontsize = 8)
p.set_ylabel('value', fontsize = 8)
p.tick_params(labelsize=5)

p1.set_xlabel('time', fontsize = 8)
p1.set_ylabel('value', fontsize = 8)
p1.tick_params(labelsize=5)

plt.xticks(rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')

plt.show()
```

График:

[image: график]

Comment: График : https://ibb.co/DYs2zDR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А у вас время не превратилось в тип "датавремя". Оно осталось строкой. Поэтому такой странный эффект. Преобразуйте колонку `time` в тип `datetime` явным образом:

```py
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df1['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['time'])
```

Только все ваши украшательства по тикам сломаются и придётся их опять переделывать, подбирать параметры.

Comment: Спасибо большое, сейчас попробую!

Comment: решило проблему, спасибо!